# What happens when grid classes apply to devices with smaller breakpoint size

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, applying any .col-md- class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg- class is not present.

Now if we use

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">div 1</div>
 <div class="col-lg-4">div 1</div>
 <div class="col-lg-4">div 1</div>
```

It will layout as three columns on a row, when we narrow down the screen size, it will break into three vertical blocks.

So my question is: **Do bootstrap do something to make that happen or just leave it as it is?**

Any good suggestions when we apply grid classes? Since col-xs-* can also be applied to large screens. So in real lift real project, what does you do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this question, It's better to understand the way which Twitter bootstrap's grid system work

### How Twitter Bootstrap detects devices

> **[Media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)**
>
> We use the following media queries in our Less files to create the key
>   breakpoints in our grid system.

```css
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

By the use of `min-width`, the following code block would be applied to all screen widths which are higher than the breakpoint value.

E.g. CSS rulesets for *medium devices* would be applied to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to `992px` And in this range of screen sizes, it would override the rulesets belonging to *small devices* (In compliance with the order of `col-sm-* col-md-*`).

And for *extra small devices*, CSS rulesets are not specified by media queries. I.e they're places normally within the stylesheet and they would be applied to elements *no matter what the screen width of the device is*, unless it get overridden by a `@media` query.

Considering the following structure (**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9qbhx24m/)**):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

The Applied CSS would be:

- **On extra small devices**

  - *first div:* Nothing. Hence, as a block level element it fills the entire width of its parent.
  - *second div:* `.col-xs-6 { width: 50%; }`
- **On small devices**

  - *first div:* Nothing. Hence, as a block level element it fills the entire width of its parent.
  - *second div:* `.col-xs-6 { width: 50%; }`
- **On medium devices**

  - *first div:* `@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-8 { width: 66.66666667%; }`
  - *second div:* `@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-4 { width: 33.33333333%; }`
- **On large devices**

  - *first div:* `@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-8 { width: 66.66666667%; }`
  - *second div:* `@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-4 { width: 33.33333333%; }`

As can be seen, the first `<div>` is displayed as a normal block level element on *Extra Small* and *Small* devices while on *Medium devices* it's affected by the media query.

Therefore, if you decrease the window size to less than `992px`, the first `<div>` will fill the whole of horizontal space within its parent element.

> Do bootstrap do something to make that happen<sup>**(1)**</sup> or just leave it as
>   it is<sup>**(2)**</sup>?

**- (2) is correct:** it just leaves it as it is.

### When/Where to apply grid classes

Actually it's up to you. However just because `col-xs-* can also be applied to large screens`, it doesn't mean that it **should be** or **must be**.

If you need to break the columns into vertical blocks on *extra small devices*, start from `col-sm-*` grid classes. Or if you want to achieve that on *small devices*, use `col-md-*` or `col-lg-*` classes.

And by using `col-lg-*` you'll override the `col-md-*` on *large devices*. Just make sure the order of classes is like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-* col-sm-* col-md-* col-lg-*">
```